# sshd on fedora 16 - unable to log in from internal network

Tags: ssh, fedora

I'm trying to access a new installation of fedora 16 that runs sshd service,with putty from a machine that lays in the same network.
sshd is enabled and started and i'm able to ssh to it from the machine itself (ssh 127.0.0.1)
from the remote machine(in the same network) i'm able to ping the fedora successfully.
selinux is disabled.
fw (a simple home router) is not blocking anything.
I'm able to ssh to a different server with sshd service running without any issues.
in the problematic target machine (new fedora 16) i captured the packets received using wireshark and it seems i have a permissions issue:
from A to fedora16 > ssh [SYN]
from fedora16 to A > Destination unreachable (Host administratively prohibited)
..
.. repeat few times

any clue? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iptables firewall on the server is rejecting the connection. Run `system-config-firewall` or `system-config-firewall-tui` and allow incoming connections on TCP port 22 (SSH).

Comment: +1 for mgorven . Thanx!! works like a charm...I forgot about the iptables. when i turn 15rep i'll remember to come back and vote up. thanks again